# Standard Error, why divide by square root of 2?

Tags: statistics

I am currently reading the book *Options, Futures and Other Derivatives* from John C. Hull. In the Chapter of Introducing the Balck-Scholes Model, it says:

> The standard error of this estimate can be shown to be approximately
>   $\hat{\sigma}/\sqrt{2n}$, where $\hat{\sigma}$ is the estimated sample
>   standard deviation, $n$ is the number of samples.

Does anyone have any idea why is $\sqrt{2n}$ and not $\sqrt{n}$?

P.S.

I have sent a Email to Prof. John C. Hull, he says: "It is tied in with the properties of the Chi squared distribution", anyone has a clue?

Comment: I guess $\hat \sigma$ is the estimated _population_ SD, based on a sample. And that $n$ is the number of _observations._ Without knowing the model, I can't say why the "2" is there. Wikipedia on 'Black-Scholes' didn't help me. Can you elaborate a bit? What estimator has this SE?

Comment: For anyone who needs more information to answer the question, you can find the relevant text on page 305 here: http://polymer.bu.edu/hes/rp-hull12.pdf

Comment: It seems to come from the $\frac12$ in [Itô's lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/It%C3%B4%27s_lemma)

Comment: I have sent a Email to Prof.  John C. Hull, he says: "It is tied in with the properties of the Chi squared distribution", anyone has a clue?